# Webpack: Error: Can't resolve 'MyCustomPath/'

Tags: reactjs, webpack

My `webpack.config.js` :

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './app/components/App.js',
    resolve: {
        alias: {
          Base: './app/components/Base',
          Modules: './app/components/Modules',
          Screens: './app/components/Screens',
          Units: './app/components/Units'
        }
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: {
            loader: "babel-loader"
            },
        }
      ]
    }
  };
```

In App.js i'm trying to import like this:

```
import NotifyModal from 'Modules/NotifyModal';
import Preloader from 'Base/Elements/Preloader';
```

But i get the following error:

```
ERROR in ./app/components/App.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'Base/Elements/Preloader' in '/home/cpt/Desktop/development/app/components'
 @ ./app/components/App.js 34:0-56 163:29-42

ERROR in ./app/components/App.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'Modules/NotifyModal' in '/home/cpt/Desktop/development/app/components'
 @ ./app/components/App.js 51:0-46 124:29-36
```

Tell me, please, what am I doing wrong? There are a lot of aliases in my application, but they do not work

Comment: Hey, can you try updating webpack to the latest version and see if the error persists? A solution I've found online have recommended this command `npm link webpack`

Comment: And the documentation was read?
```Base: path.resolve (__dirname, 'app/components/Base/')
...```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't had much success using webpack's `alias` feature, it never worked for me. Instead, I use this babel plugin: [babel-plugin-module-resolver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-module-resolver).

To use it, you create a custom `babel.config.js` file like so:

```
module.exports = function(api) {
    api.cache(true);

    return {
        presets: [ "@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
        plugins: [
            [
                "module-resolver", 
                {
                   // put your aliases here; I use a tilde (~) to represent
                   // that the folder is aliased, but you don't have to
                    alias: {
                        ~actions: "./src/actions",
                        ~components: "./src/components",
                        ~containers: "./src/containers",
                        ~pages: "./src/pages",
                        ~reducers: "./src/reducers",
                        ~root: "./src/root",
                        ~routes: "./src/routes",
                        ~sagas: "./src/sagas",
                        ~styles: "./src/styles",
                        ~types: "./src/types",
                        ~utils: "./src/utils",
                    },
                },
            ],
            "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
            "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
            ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", { loose: true }],
        ],
    };
};
```

Then you can reference one of the aliased folders like so: `import App from "~components/App"` (assuming `App` is a folder that contains an `index.js` file).

However, as you can you see, the above approach is pretty repetitive, where you have to manually add aliases. So I created this function to traverse a specific folder and alias all the top-level folders within them:

```
const { readdirSync, statSync } = require("fs");
const { resolve } = require("path");

// read all directories within the path specified below 
// and reduce (loop) through them
const readDirectory = path =>
    readdirSync(path).reduce((acc, folder) => {
        // combine the path with the current folder name
        // for example: "./src/components"
        const dirPath = `${path}${folder}`; 

        // check that the directory (dirPath) exists
        if (statSync(resolve(dirPath)).isDirectory()) { 
            // add the folder as an alias, for example: 
            // "~components": "./src/components" 
            // to the accumulator (an object)
            acc[`~${folder.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, "")}`] = dirPath;  
        }

        // return the accumulated object of directories
        return acc; 
    }, {});

// read all top-level directories within "./src/"
const alias = readDirectory("./src/");

module.exports = function(api) {
    api.cache(true);

    return {
        presets: [ "@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
        plugins: [
            [
                "module-resolver",
                { alias } // apply aliased folder to module resolver options object
            ],
            "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
            "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
            ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", { loose: true }],
        ],
    };
};
```

On a side note, I personally avoid aliasing top-level root folders (folders that sit outside of `src`); however, if you want to, then you can tweak the function above to include a [list folders to read and ignore](https://github.com/mattcarlotta/nextjs-ssr-kit/blob/master/babel.config.js#L4-L22) (because you don't want to alias `node_modules` or `.git` folders). Again, not recommended nor needed if you just alias within the `src` folder.